# Bitwise manipulate address

Tags: c

I have an address in hexadecimal, say 007b183c. I want to change its bits.
I have read a bit (no pun intended) about bit shifting and masking but I don't know how to get the address in bit-format so to speak. How do I do this?

Comment: Um, well you don't get it into any "bit format", it's a number already, so just do your math on it.

Comment: It's in bytes. So if I increment it by 1, I move to the next byte (sizeof(char)). I can't get a hold of the bits so to speak.

Comment: Your questions is to broad.  Voted to close.  Read up on bitwise manipulation of values in C.  If you are still confused, ask specific questions to the task that you are trying to complete.  Also, be sure to search and check if someone else has asked your question.  You sound new to coding so, assuredly, someone already has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about manipulating *address* bits, if you have an address such as this:

```
char * p = (char *)0x007b183c;
```

and you want to do some sort of bit manipulation such as, say, rounding up to the next 16 byte aligned address, then you cast to a suitable int type, do the manipulation, and cast back, e.g.

```
char *p_aligned - (char *)(((uint_ptr_t)p + 15) & ~15); // p_aligned = 0x007b1840
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you have a pointer to some location, and want to move it around in **bits**.

That won't work. The pointer points to a byte location, that is indivisible in this sense. The lowest bit of the address specifies what byte that is.

You will have to either read the neighbour byte and then use those two to get the value you want, or something in that sense, but you can't point to individual bits.

Comment: I don't want to 'move' it. I just want to place bits in the address that I can use for later. These bits are never used by the address I assume since as you said, the smallest amount of memory that can be allocated is 8 bits.

Comment: I don't think you really understand what I wrote. The address is INDEX of the byte it points to. There are no unused bits in it.